# Repetition of class constraints in instances

Tags: haskell

Why does the first instance declaration require an explicit mention of `Num a` where the second does not? Why can't `Num` be equally inferred by the class constraint of `C1` in both cases?

```
class Num a => C1 a b
instance (Num a, C1 a Int) => C1 a Char

class C1 a b => C2 a b
instance C2 a Int => C2 a Char
```

Comment: The former does not, afaik. If you write `C1 a Int`, then this is sufficient.

Comment: It may depend on GHC version and options. At GHC-8.0.1 with -XFlexibleContexts, -XFlexibleInstances, -XUndecidableInstances, -XMultiParamTypeClasses (except the defaults) I get compilation error "Could not deduce (Num a), arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration" from the 1st instance if I remove the Num constaint